# Ajax request to external url using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im trying to do an ajax request to an external url.Right now im doing it in php

as

```
$data = array(
        'TokenID' => $tokenid,
        'APIKey' => $api_key,
        'EcryptedData' => $encrypted_data,
        'TokenScheme' => 4
    );
    //convert to JSON
    $json = json_encode($data);
    //curl config
       $ch = curl_init("https://testingonetwo.com/rest/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                    'Content-Type: application/json', //we are using json in this example, you could use xml as well
                                    'Content-Length: '.strlen($json),
                                    'Accept: application/json')       //we are using json in this example, you could use xml as well
                                    );
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

       $outputjson = curl_exec($ch);
```

Im trying to do the same using javascript.I tried this using jquery,but didnt work out

code for jquery which I tried is

```
$data = array(
        'TokenID' => $tokenid,
        'APIKey' => $api_key,
        'EcryptedData' => $encrypted_data,
        'TokenScheme' => 4);
$json = json_encode($data);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://testingonetwo.com/rest/',
    data: {data:$json},
    success: success,
    dataType: "json"
});
alert(result);
function success(result) { 
    alert('done');
}
```

Im new to both the client side browser scripts.Kindly help me try the above to javascript,which I prefer.Looking forward for some help.

Comment: You are json-encoding to $json but sending $data

Comment: you cannot access other domains through javascript, you will get a cross domain access error. Unless the other domain uses cors or they employ jsonp responses you will not be able to get the data.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Is there anyway I could do it?Some work arounds?

Comment: @niklas Sorry that was a typoo

Comment: Use a middleman, ie call your php script above let it get the json data and simply echo it out, and instead of pointing the ajax call to the other domain point the url to that php script

Comment: Yeah,but I`m giving a javascript to my client,which he can use and he dont need to add any other things to be done in the scripting side.So that is why im trying to do it through javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the server does not support cors, or does not employ JSONP responses you will need to use a middleman script to get the data.

JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://YourOwnDomain.com/myPhpScript.php',
    success: success,
    dataType: "json"
});
```

PHP

```
...
$outputjson = curl_exec($ch);
echo $outputjson;
die;
```

If they employ jsonp responses you can use jQuery's jsonp abilities to get the data, look at the other domain's documentation on how to call their rest service they should have details about doing a jsonp call if they do allow it. The general code would be something like:

```
$data = {
        'TokenID':$tokenid,
        'APIKey':$api_key,
        'EcryptedData':$encrypted_data,
        'TokenScheme':4};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://testingonetwo.com/rest/?callback=?',
    data: {data:$data},
    success: success,
    dataType: "jsonp"
});
```

But as you have what looks like a API key and a TokenID if these are supposed to be secret (ie the end users should not be able to see them) then you shouldnt use the javascript that shows those details, ie use the middleman script.